# How to make a joint fetch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I got three objects:

**User**

- Id
- Firstname
- Lastname

**Conversation**

- Id
- Entity_type
- Entity_subtype

**Assignment**

- Id
- User_id
- Assignable_id (ID of Conversation)
- Assignable_type (Class name of Conversation)

One or more Users are connected to a Conversation through Assignments.
I am trying to create a query that checks if two Users are having a direct message Conversation or I need to create a new one automatically.

I have this code and it "works" (I get no error) but it returns a Conversation even though only one of the Users are involved in a Conversation. But I need it to only return a Conversation if Both Users share the Same Conversation, ie they are talking to each other.

```
Conversation.where(entity_type: "conversation", entity_subtype: "direct").joins(:assignments).where(:assignments => {:user_id => ["cdd3c6be-ac78-46f2-a7ae-7f2299b6fedb", "32117e53-9b2f-49c6-8cc8-3a9eb9003a2e"] })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is by using GROUP and using HAVING to set a condition on the group:

```
class Conversion < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.between(*users)
    joins(:assignments)
      .group(:id)
      .where(assignments: { user_id: users })
      .having(Assignment.arel_table[:id].count.eq(users.length))
  end
end
```

The advantage is that this approach can be used with any number of users.

If you change out `.eq` to `.gteq` you can get conversions that include the two users but isn't a private conversation. On Postgres you can use `Assignment.arel_table[Arel.star]` as an optimization.

Comment: Thanks @max, I try to use it like this: Conversation.where(entity_type: "conversation", entity_subtype: "direct").between(users) but I get the error: undefined method `id' for #<Conversation::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000106b54120>

Comment: You may need to explicitly turn it into a list of IDs in Rails 5 with for example `users.ids`.

Comment: Users parameter is an Array of two User ids, is that wrong?

Comment: You can either use the splat operator to turn the array into a list for example: `Conversion.between(*[1, 2])` or you can change the method defintion so that it takes a single argument.

Comment: This produces the same error: Conversation.where(entity_type: "conversation", entity_subtype: "direct").between(*users)

Comment: Are you sure the error is directly tied to this method? I don't have Rails 5 installed but this works just fine in Rails 7 and is a tried and true approach.

Comment: Most likely not, I will try to find the issue. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: `{user_id: users}` should be `{user: users}` right @max ?

Comment: Not sure, depends, is user_id the attribute on Assignment?

Comment: @dileepnandanam both have the exact same result. `{user_id: users}` is more explicit. `{ user: users }` will use the assocation to figure out what column you wanted to query.

Answer (score 1):

Join assignments twice and in resulting rows, pick a row with assignment user ids match.

```
user_ids = ["cdd3c6be-ac78-46f2-a7ae-7f2299b6fedb", "32117e53-9b2f-49c6-8cc8-3a9eb9003a2e"]

Conversation
  .where(entity_type: "conversation", entity_subtype: "direct")
  .joins("LEFT JOIN assignments as1 ON assignments.assignable_id = conversations.id AND assignments.assignable_type = 'Conversation'")
  .joins("LEFT JOIN assignments as2 ON assignments.assignable_id = conversations.id AND assignments.assignable_type = 'Conversation'")
  .where('as1.user_id = as2.user_id')
  .where('as1.user_id = ? AND as2.user_id = ?', user_ids[0], user_ids[1])
```

Will give you list of convos, both are involved